# How to integrate an Appium flutter driver automation suite(Java) with BrowserStack?

Tags: flutter, appium, browserstack-app-automate

I have created an Appium flutter driver automation project(Java) and I need to integrate it with browser stack. Any support on it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Browserstack does support testing of Flutter Apps Using Appium Automation. Follow this public document: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/test-flutter-apps-with-appium